# How can I implement priority queue or heap in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, heap

I have:

```
words = ["i", "love", "leet", "i", "love", "code"]
k = 3
```

`"i"` and `"love"` show up twice, but `"leet"` and `"code"` show up once. I want:

```
["i", "love", "code"]
```

instead of `"leet"`. This code:

```
words.group_by(&:itself).sort_by {|_, s| -s.length}.first(k).map(&:first)
```

will display:

```
["i", "love", "leet"]
```

What is a good way to solve this issue?

It can be solved using a heap, but Ruby does not support Heap. Is there any recommendation? I would like to do it without using a gem so that I can demo at an online code test site.

==========================================================================
`k` is for frequency
So this question is for find k frequency words in the words array.
when k is 3 issue I counter is choosing `code` not `leet`. I want to sort by alphabet order when there is same frequency words, so I can pick first one.

Comment: What does k stand for? What tells how to prioritize? Maybe you can expand the example? I have the idea to use rotate, but need more details to test.

Comment: I mean, `words.rotate(k).first(k)` gives the required output, but what if the array is longer? And how to manage the show up count?

Comment: array looks simple enough, did you try `words[3..-1]`? Not sure how heap or Priority Queue will solve this problem. If you have got such array with huge amount of data then probably it's more of NLP problem to solve. Without knowing what exactly is required/logic to form/capture a particular sentence will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort alphabetically when the frequency is the same, *do sort alphabetically*:

```
words.group_by { |w| w }.
      sort_by { |w, a| [-a.size, w] }. # ⇐ HERE
      map(&:first).
      first(3)
#⇒ ["i", "love", "code"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am not familiar with writing code inside of `{}` block. Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: I am not sure what’s specific with writing code inside `{}` block. It’s exactly the same code as outside.